# Asp .net validator without changing style

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have created a design using asp .net. On clicking the submit button a validator message will come but style is changed. I have seen that "required" keyword is used for showing validator message in php and it won't change any style. Is it possible to use such a validator in asp .net?

I have tried:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControltoValidate"Control Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

But I need to show the error message as pop up.

Comment: What code /styling have you tried so far ?

Comment: Edit your original question. Do not add code in the comments as people will miss it and your question is less likely to get answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. Set `ShowMessageBox="true"` in your `ValidationSummary` control;
2. Set `Display="none"` in your `RequiredFieldValidator` control;

Example:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControltoValidate"Control Name" Display="none" />

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="MyValidationSummary" runat="server"
                   ShowMessageBox="true"
                   ShowSummary="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I believe you are looking for a validation example in ASP.net.

Please see the simple example I have for you below:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/Blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
                if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
                    $("#validation_dialog").dialog({
                        title: "Validation Error!",
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        buttons: {
                            Close: function () {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        </script>
        Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtName"
            runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        Email:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
            runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
        <div id="validation_dialog" style="display: none">
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah I need a validation in ASP .net. But I doesn't need to change on the style on showing message. If it shows as a pop up style won't change.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CoolBoy/h4k5s/  Please go through this link I need to show like this in asp .net

Comment: I have updated my question to use a popup. please see the edited version and if this is what you are looking for please mark as answered, Thanks

Comment: Here you use AJAX controls but I don't have permission to use that.

Comment: The example is using jQuery and Javascript.